# uninitialised constant after upgrade of Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I've just updated my Gemfile.

At the beginning I thought problem came from `Zeitwerk` (from `2.4.2` to `2.5.4`) but I've downgraded it and I still have an issue on my spec. I've isolated that the problem does not come from `RSpec` and dependencies.

Actually, RSpec does not found a class which is defined within another file and does not match the file name/class name.

**Important point:** `Filter::MyStandardError` is found.

```rb
# app/services/filter/my_standard_error.rb
module Filter
  class MyStandardError < StandardError; end

  class MySpecificError < MyStandardError; end
  # ...
end
```

```rb
# app/services/filter/my_tested_service.rb
module Filter
  class MyTestedService

    def initialize
      raise ::Filter::MySpecificError
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
RSpec.describe Filter::MyTestedService do
  subject { described_class.new }

  it 'raises an error'
    expect{subject}.to raise_error(::Filter::MySpecificError)
  end
end
```

And I got the error:

```
NameError:
       uninitialized constant Filter::MySpecificError
```

I got the [Changelog](https://github.com/fxn/zeitwerk/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md) but breaking changes are not used on my configuration.

Does anybody have an idea for this one?

Answer (score 0):

After reading [one-file-one-constant-at-the-same-top-level](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#one-file-one-constant-at-the-same-top-level)

I found this to fix my issue

```rb
# app/services/filter.rb
class Filter
  class MyStandardError < StandardError; end

  class MySpecificError < MyStandardError; end
end
```

```rb
# app/services/filter/my_tested_service.rb
class Filter
  class MyTestedService

    def initialize
      raise ::Filter::MySpecificError
    end
  end
end
```

I still don't know why it was working before..

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to add `app/services` to the autoload paths, that is done automatically by Rails. I'd suggest to remove that configuration to keep things simple/idiomatic.

The implementation of `app/services/filter.rb` should not be needed. Your application is doing something that is not right, we just need to find it.

Could you please delete `app/services/filter.rb`, throw `Rails.autoloaders.log!` in `config/application.rb`, trigger the error, and share the traces?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define two constants at the same level in the same file. It is one constant, one file. This has not changed in Zeitwerk upgrades. You need one file for the standard error, and another file for the specific error.

Comment: Then I don't understand why it was working before the upgrade.  When adding `Rails.autoloaders.log!` on `config/application.rb`. I got the file `app/services/filter/my_standard_error.rb` without the patch I found. But if it's "one file, one constant", it should never have worked since the beginning isn't it?

Comment: Actually, [the closed issue #51](https://github.com/fxn/zeitwerk/issues/51) is exactly my case I think. If I understand [this](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#one-file-one-constant-at-the-same-top-level) correctly, it means I'll need to switch from `module Filter` to `class Filter` isn't it? But in my case it does not make sense since I've all classes/files related to the feature on the same folder `filter`.

Comment: I've made an [update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71335300/2616474) with comment you posted. Is it correct do to it that way? One file defining what was a `module` before and describing all error classes inside.

Comment: Yes, that alternative is going to work. You'll be able to autoload, and also to reload cleanly. 